# Build failed importing a const double with extern directive

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a file:

```
#import "OutletsHandler.h"


@implementation OutletsHandler

- (IBAction) pi : (id) sender
{
    extern const double PI; // here I try to import PI
    [textField setDoubleValue: PI];
}

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) 
{
}

return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

OutletsHandler.h imports CalculatorScanner.h, this is CalculatorScanner.h:

```
#import <stdbool.h>

const double PI=3.141592654;
```

But I get semantic issues:

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
ld: duplicate symbol _PI in /Users/ramy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-   crcetknqiorefpbjxcrtydequwxf/Build/Intermediates/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CalculatorScanner.o and /Users/ramy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-crcetknqiorefpbjxcrtydequwxf/Build/Intermediates/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CalculatorAppDelegate.o for architecture x86_64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are *defining* `PI` in `CalculatorScanner.h`, when you should just be *declaring* it.  To make it compile and link properly, put this in `CalculatorScanner.h`:

```
extern const double PI;
```

and put this in `CalculatorScanner.cpp`:

```
const double PI = 3.141592654;
```

But that's not really the correct solution either, in this case.  The correct solution here is to use the standard constant `M_PI` instead of defining your own (less accurate) constant.

Comment: The problems is that I get the error even if I only declare const double PI=3.141592654; without using it anywhere.It seems like xcode finds a duplicate variabile.
This is the full error: http://pastebin.com/krZEhHuA

Comment: Maybe because of double inclusion: I use the import directive, but can't figure out how to fix that (even using include instead of import the error is still there).

Answer (score 0):

There is a scope problem there if you mean to use extern, you cant do it in a method, it has to be at global scope.